# Javascript: capture value to use in form action field of Laravel app

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have a Laravel app with a Javascript function that captures some data which I'm using to dynamically fill a modal box.

```
$(function() {
    $('#edit-auction-modal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
     var auctionId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
     console.log(auctionId);
     //auctionId has the correct value for the selected auction. This needs to be used in the View file
    });
});
```

In the view file, I have a modal box with a form (to update the fields).

```
<div id="edit-auction-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title" id="auctionLabel"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body edit-content" style="padding-top:10px">
                     <form method="POST" action="{!! route('admin_auctions_update', ['id' => auctionId ]) !!}">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                      {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                      ....
                     </form>
```

Using the above code, nothing gets updated as it tries to send to 'auctions/auctionId/update' instead of 'auctions/1/update' or 'auctions/2/update'

How can change this so that I can use the value of auction0id (from the JS file) in my view?

Should be pretty trivial I think but my JS skills are below average...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#edit-auction-modal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
        var auctionId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        var pattern = /(auctions\/)(.+)(\/update)/;
        var action = $('form').attr('action');
        $('form').attr('action', action.replace(pattern, "$1" + auctionId + "$3"));
    });
});
```

---

Explanation:

The view is handled **server-side** and defines the html originally sent to the browser. You don't run any PHP code past this point. Since `auctionId` only exists as a result of **client-side** events, your only tool for modifying the `action` attribute is JavaScript.

So, in the view you just include the JS script, as I assume you already are. Also, you could write the original action as `{!! route('admin_auctions_update', ['id' => 0 ]) !!}` (`0` as some default placeholder value).

Finally the Regular Expressions explanation: parentheses define capture groups, which you can then access by number. So, the first one contains the string contents before the id to be replaced, the second one the id itself, and the third one the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What needs to come in the view file. Would it be just this: <form method="POST" id="auction-form" action=""> ? For me to understand: what is the $1 and $3?

Comment: I get the principle. While the code should dynamically update the action, it seems it always uses the original action (with id = 0). I added a console.log(action); statement in the JS file and it always logs out http://localhost:5000/admin/auctions/0 indeed.

Comment: Actually, try logging `action.replace(pattern, "$1" + auctionId + "$3")` since this doesn't change the value of `action`. Also, should'nt it be `localhost:5000/admin/auctions/123/update` anyway?

Comment: It works. As part of debugging I had indeed changed the route (without /update). I forgot to add it back, so your pattern did not match. I fixed it now and it works as you suggested! Many thanks...Saves me quite some time!

Comment: great, glad I could help